# Count number of rows that were returned in a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count, common-table-expression

This query successfully returns only the first row of a join that could potentially have more than one row.

```
WITH RevisionProducts AS (
    SELECT
        qr.LeadID,
        p.Code,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY qr.LeadID ORDER BY qr.LeadID DESC) rownumber
    FROM    
        QuoteRevisions qr
        JOIN ...
)
SELECT 
    l.LeadID,
    ...
    co.Name,
    rp1.Code,
    0 AS CodeCount
FROM 
    Leads l
    JOIN Companies co on co.CompanyID = l.CompanyID
    JOIN RevisionProducts rp1 ON rp1.LeadID = l.ID AND rp1.rownumber = 1
```

What I want to do now is replace...

```
0 AS CodeCount
```

...with the actual number of rows that *would have been* returned in the join, had we allowed them all.  Can't figure out how to do this.

I'm not sure I need the CTE, but I figured it might be handy since I most likely need to reference the same query again for the count?

**EDIT:**

Ok it looks like I need to be more clear.  So the query with in the CTE... let's  run it with a WHERE clause:

```
    SELECT
        qr.LeadID,
        p.Code,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY qr.LeadID ORDER BY qr.LeadID DESC) rownumber
    FROM    
        QuoteRevisions qr
        JOIN ...
    WHERE
        qr.LeadID = 151
```

And let's say that query returns 5 rows.  So, in the first query, if we DID NOT limit the join to the first row only, then the join would have returned 5 rows when Lead.LeadID got to 151.  So in the final dataset, there would have been 5 rows that were identical except for the rp1.Code column.

I have already limited the number of rows to 1, which is what I wanted. But now, I want to know how many rows would have been returned.

I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: I am totally confused here. What does "would have been returned in the join, had we allowed them all" mean? I have read that over and over and it just doesn't make any sense to me at all. Are you trying to get the count of rows per some group? Have you looked at using COUNT? You are going to have to provide some more details before we can help here. This would be a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Good feedback.  See my edit to the OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
WITH RevisionProducts AS (
    SELECT
        qr.LeadID,
        p.Code,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY qr.LeadID ORDER BY qr.LeadID DESC) rownumber
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY qr.LeadID ) rowcount
    FROM    
        QuoteRevisions qr
        JOIN ...
)
SELECT 
    l.ID,
    ...
    co.Name,
    rp1.Code,
    rp1.rowcount AS CodeCount
FROM 
    Leads l
    JOIN Companies co on co.CompanyID = l.CompanyID
    JOIN RevisionProducts rp1 ON rp1.LeadID = l.ID AND rp1.rownumber = 1
```